# HERE Api: Using Positioning APIto get Lat and Long

Tags: php, rest, api, here-api

I'm trying to use the Using Positioning API to search for the latitude and longitude of a given point, however I only have MCC, MNC, TimeAdvance, LAC, Cell_ID, and Signal Power. How can I use this data to fetch the location?
I tried to use as below but did not return any data.

```
{
  "gsm": [
      {
          "mcc": 724,
          "mnc": 10,
          "lac": 2397,
          "cid": 453,
          "nmr": [{ "bsic": "0", "bcch": "0" }]
      },
      {
          "mcc": 724,
          "mnc": 10,
          "lac": 2397,
          "cid": 3045,
          "nmr": [{ "bsic": "0", "bcch": "0" }]
      }
  ]
}
```

Im using cURL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response means that you have sent a valid request for which the API cannot determine a location.

I have tried to find the cell towers in your request using various cell tower databases and I could not find them anywhere. If they do exist they are most likely not in our (or any) database at this point.